# Should ASCII control characters be stripped from documents before sending to Vespa?

Tags: vespa

I'm trying to store a document into Vespa with a string field. When using the document-api http endpoint it's getting rejected with a parsing error. I've validated that the correct JSON is being sent (other documents go through fine).

Here is the error message that I'm seeing:

```
PARSER_ERROR Error in document 'id:x:y:n=1:1FVzo2l7mMLticB0WMkBKIECMLzAg' - could not parse field 'content' of type 'string': The string field value contains illegal code point 0xB
```

I can see that there's a check for these sorts of characters (vertical tab in my case) `com.yahoo.text.Text` in `allowedAsciiChars` but I don't see anywhere in the documentation that I should be stripping these chars before sending to Vespa. In fact I see sort of the opposite situation where Vespa will go out of its way to replace certain chars behind the scenes without rejecting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please strip ASCII control characters from the documents before feeding.

I will update the documentation, although is seems the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-8) says these control characters must be escaped, so these are implicitly not allowed in the feed

Comment: Does this apply only to feeding via the http endpoint or for the Java feeder as well? Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure we were escaping the control characters when sending them but will double check.

Answer (score 1):

> I see sort of the opposite situation where Vespa will go out of its way to replace certain chars behind the scenes

Where do you see this?

There is a Text.stripInvalidCharacters utility method provided as a utility for clients in Java which need to strip characters from non-sanitized text.

Comment: I meant that in reference to linguistics processing like accent normalization, which of course is not really the same as control character handling.